# chef powershell command doesn't work

Tags: ruby, powershell, chef-infra, quoting

I'm trying to get ACLs and parse into the array `reg_perms`, the code works fine without the `Where-Object{($_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users")`

```
command ='powershell "(Get-Acl \'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\').Access | Where-Object{($_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Users")} | Format-List RegistryRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference"'

    data = ::Mixlib::ShellOut.new(command).run_command.stdout.strip.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")
    reg_perms = data.split("\n\n").each_with_object([]) do |set, arr|
      arr << set.split("\n").map do |f|
        f.split(':').collect(&:strip)
      end.to_h
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes for your entire string: `'`. Then when your string is evaled with double quotes the double quotes around the `BUILTIN\Users` string are not escaped, this mean you need to escape the double quotes around the `""BUILTIN\Users""` the powershell way or use single quotes `\'BUILTIN\Users\'` and escape them the ruby way.

This should work:

```
command ='powershell "(Get-Acl \'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\').Access | Where-Object{
    ($_.IdentityReference -eq \'BUILTIN\Users\')
} | Format-List RegistryRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference"'
```

Comment: Hmm guess that might make sense would have to play with it to fully understand. Your executing process must be evaluating it odd potentially as it see nested qoutes. I am not familiar with Ruby but if they have it you could try a literal string where no escaping is needed and see what happens.

Comment: Also powershell does not escape quotes via a \, so if that works then Ruby is doing the escaping and it is the source of the issue. Powershells escape character is the tick.

Comment: Correction to what I said earlier: `\"` is the safe way to escape literal `"` inside a `"..."` command passed to PowerShell from `cmd.exe` (which could be interactive, from a batch file, or from Chef/Ruby). `""` - even though a safe choice PowerShell-_internally_ - works in _some_ cases, but it's not obvious when it fails, so it is best avoided; an example of when `""` fails (execute directly from `cmd.exe`): `powershell -nop -command "'>>""BUILTIN\Users""<<'"`

Comment: And, just to demonstrate that `\"`-escaping does work (even though you wouldn't expect it, given that PowerShell-_internally_ things work differently): `powershell -nop -command "'>>\"BUILTIN\Users\"<<'"` executed from `cmd.exe` correctly outputs `>>"BUILTIN\Users"<<`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to embed `"BUILTIN\Users"` - a double-quoted string - within the overall double-quoted command string you're passing to the PowerShell executable (`powershell "..."`), which cannot work, because **embedding the same type of quotes in a quoted string requires *escaping***.

**PowerShell, when it is called from *outside* via its CLI (`powershell.exe`), requires that *embedded* `"` chars. be `\"`-escaped** (even though PowerShell-*internally*, `` `" `` or `""` are used).<sup>[1]</sup>

Since you're using *single*-quoting on the Ruby (Chef) side (`command = '...'`), escaping the *inner* embedded `"` chars. as `\"` for the sake of *PowerShell* is sufficient.

Therefore, replace `-eq "BUILTIN\Users"` with `-eq \"BUILTIN\Users\"`; i.e.:

```
command ='powershell "(Get-Acl \'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\').Access | Where-Object{($_.IdentityReference -eq \"BUILTIN\Users\")} | Format-List RegistryRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference"'
```

---

**Alternatively** - given that the *content* of your quoted string is a *literal*, **you can use *single* quotes around `BUILTIN\Users`** in the PowerShell command; in that case, however, because on the Ruby side you're using single quotes for the overall command, **you need to escape the embedded `'` instances as `\'` for *Ruby*'s benefit**:

Therefore, replace `-eq "BUILTIN\Users"` with `-eq \'BUILTIN\Users\'`; i.e.:

```
command ='powershell "(Get-Acl \'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\').Access | Where-Object{($_.IdentityReference -eq \'BUILTIN\Users\')} | Format-List RegistryRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference"'
```

---

<sup>[1] When calling the PowerShell CLI from `cmd.exe` - be it from the command prompt, a batch file, or via Chef/Ruby - escaping a literal `"` as `""` *sometimes* , but not always works (try

`powershell -Command "'Nat ""King"" Cole'"` directly from a `cmd.exe` command prompt).

Instead, `\"`-escaping is the safe choice.

`` `" ``-escaping, which is the *typical* PowerShell-*internal* way to escape `"` inside `"..."`, *never* works in this scenario.</sup>